# How do we check whether any item in the listbox is selected in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

I have to do a for loop and check whether any of the items are checked if I want to know if any of the items are checked.

In C#, there is something like

```
listbox.SelectedItems.Count();
```

Is there any similar method for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to loop through them.

Comment: what about checking the selectedindex? if that is less than 0, not selected. else at least one item is selected. But I wonder whether that is reliable..

Comment: Yeah, you may be right about that. It wouldn't accomplish what the OP wants to accomplish. But it could be used to quickly determine if nothing is selected, and be faster in that case.

Answer (score 40):

you can see whether any item is selected by the below code:

```
if (listboxname.SelectedIndex == -1)
       MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item first!");
```

Comment: This does indeed tell you if there are any at all. We could use it as a check.  If there are, then and only then, loop through them. That will save some processing time.

Comment: This did not work if the user selects only the first item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN and my experience, you have to go over all the items, to do this:

> you can determine the selected item(s)
>   in the ListBox control by enumerating
>   the Items collection and testing the
>   Selected value for each ListItem
>   element.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be available in 2.0 though...but another option is to query the Items collection with LINQ.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856152/using-linq-to-convert-listbox-items-values-to-int) for info on that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I may have found a solution for you. I don't know how effective it is. But here it is:

```
if (listbox.SelectedIndex <= -1)
{
    listbox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
if (listbox.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I may have found a solution for you. I don't know how effective it is. But here it is:

```
        if (listData.SelectedIndex>=0)
        {               
                listData.Items.Remove(listData.SelectedItem.ToString());                
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("plz select data first");
        }
```

Comment: The answer is not matching the question.

Comment: The answer is not matching the question.